# Do I need to close a tcpip socket in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sockets, tcp

I'm new to MatLab, and I'm trying to build a super simple server/client system to test some stuff out, following an example I found.

`t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(t);
data = fread(t, 10);
plot(data);`

My question is, do I need to close this socket at the end? Assuming it were part of a larger program of course. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use:

```
fclose(t);
```

when you are done with the connection. Does that answer your question?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpip.html